# $10^n+1$ is never prime?

Tags: number-theory

I tested a few numbers of the form $10^n+1$ (i.e. $100000001$) besides $11$ and $101$ and they were all composite. Clearly some of them if we have an even number of $0$'s in between are multiples of $11$, but is it just a coincidence that the ones with odd number of $0$'s are also composite?

Comment: You seem to forget $+$ somewhere.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242949/are-there-infinite-many-integer-n-ge-0-such-that-102n1-prime-numbers ...oh, and even more relevant, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34877/are-there-infinite-amount-of-primes-and-non-primes-in-110n-formed-numbers

Answer (score 7):

As André Nicolas mentions, $10^n+1$ can be prime only if $n=2^m$. These are [generalized Fermat numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFermatNumber.html), and I believe it is open if infinitely many of them are prime.  Here is some [data](http://www1.uni-hamburg.de/RRZ/W.Keller/GFN10.html) for the special case that you are interested.  In particular, the data shows that 11 and 101 are the only primes of the form $10^n+1$ for all $n$ up to $2^{23}$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not known. But the only candidate $n$ have the shape $n=2^m$. So you can confine your testing to these.