# $10^k +1$ is not prime for all $k\gt 2$?

Tags: number-theory

I know that if k is odd then $10 + 1$ divides $10^k + 1$.  This means that for $k\gt 2$ if $k$ is odd or is congruent to $2 \pmod 4$ then $10^k + 1$ is not prime.  In other words, if $k\gt 2$ is odd then $11$ divides $10^k + 1$ and if $k>2$ and congruent to $2 \pmod 4$ then $101$ divides $10^k +1$.

How can I prove that if $k$ is a multiple of $4$ then $10^k + 1$ is not prime?

I am assuming the statement is true because I have checked the cases up to $k = 3000$ using Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do is very hard, in fact if $k$ is divisible by an odd number then $10^k+1$ is not prime (the same method you used if $k$ is odd will work), otherwise $k$ is a power of two $k=2^n$ and proving that :
$$ 10^{2^n}+1$$
is never a prime is a part of the conjecture of [generalized Fermat primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_numbers), See also this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242949/are-there-infinite-many-integer-n-ge-0-such-that-102n1-prime-numbers?rq=1)

Comment: Something seems wrong...

Comment: I corrected my answer thanks for your observation